# Form in a C# application not using the default style

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm having a strange issue where a form in a C# application isn't using the normal system style. I want it to look the same as any normal Windows application, the same way it looks in the designer:
[The form in the designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisBv.png)

But when I actually run the program, it looks like this instead:
[The form when the program is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwVjO.png)

I know that the title bar is supposed to be a different style, that's fine, but the style of the buttons and checkboxes, etc is different to how it's supposed to be. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code in the Program.cs file? Usually the style is defined there before opening the firt form

Comment: The first line is `public partial class Program : Form`, but the rest of it is just normal C# code, I added the form files using `Project > Add Form` in Visual Studio, and then I open the form using `form.Show()`. The main code displays icons in the system tray, the form will just be for changing settings.

Comment: Look at the program.cs not the file for the form.

Comment: When you create a WinForms Project using the default Template, a couple of lines of code are added to Program.cs, before the starting Form is created and run: `Application.EnableVisualStyles(); Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`. The first line is what matters here.

Comment: I tried adding `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in my `Main()` method right before I do `Application.Run()` to start the program, that seems to fix parts of the issue but not all of them. Text boxes now look normal, but everything else (buttons, checkboxes, etc) still look like they did before.

Comment: Actually I seem to have fixed it completely, I just had to move `form = new Form()` into `Main()` after having called `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`. Thanks!